Errors not displaying in login form in Django
In my Django project, I use django.auth for authentication. I have two similar HTML templates for registration and login. The problem is that while displaying errors (e.g., passwords don't match, password too short) works for registration, it doesn't for logging in.
For example, if I enter an incorrect username and password and click the submit button, errors won't show up, the page refreshes, the username remains in the input box, but the password box is empty. That's all. If I provide the correct credentials, it logs me in correctly. If I display the form using {{ form.as_p }}, errors work fine.
Below are both forms:
Registration:
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <!-- Username -->
    {% if form.username.errors %}
    <ul>
        {% for error in form.username.errors %}
            <li class="small-red-text">{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
    {{form.username|add_class:"form-control"|attr:"id:register-username-input"|attr:"placeholder:Username"}}

    <!-- Password 1 -->
    {% if form.password1.errors %}
    <ul>
        {% for error in form.password1.errors %}
            <li class="small-red-text">{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
    {{form.password1|add_class:"form-control"|attr:"placeholder:Password"}}

    <!-- Password 2 -->
    {% if form.password2.errors %}
    <ul>
        {% for error in form.password2.errors %}
            <li class="small-red-text">{{ error}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
    {{form.password2|add_class:"form-control"|attr:"id:register-password-input"|attr:"placeholder:Confirm password"}}
    <button class="small-blue-button" type="submit" name="register">Register</button>
</form>

Logging:
<form id="login-form" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if form.username.errors %}
        <ul>
            {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                <li class="small-red-text">{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
        {{form.username|add_class:"form-control"|attr:"id:username-input"|attr:"placeholder:Username"}}
        {% if form.password.errors %}
        <ul>
            {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                <li class="small-red-text">{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
        {{form.password|add_class:"form-control"|attr:"id:password-input"|attr:"placeholder:Password"}}
        <button type="submit" class="small-blue-button">Login</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'mainapp:translator' %}" />
    </form>

How can I fix the login form to display errors correctly?

1. Are these rendered by the same View? If so, care to share? 2. If not 1 please share the mechanism the two different Views take to render and parse their HTML forms. Are there any striking difference?
